# Dynamically loaded images disappear after print preview

Tags: javascript, printing

Here is my print function.

```
 function printContent() {
        var myWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=600,height=700')
        var headstr = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>";
        var footstr = "</body>";
        var newstr = some text;
        myWindow.document.body.innerHTML = newstr;
        myWindow.print();
        myWindow.close();
}
```

html:

```
<div>
<div id="text"> </div>
<div id="images"></div>
</div>
```

I try to print only 'text' on page not the entire page but after preview, dynamically loaded images to 'images' div disappear. I can't solve this with update panels. Have you got any idea?? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use image as a background to its outer div instead of using image tag. Hope this helps. Please check the below code for reference.

```css
.bg__image {
  background: url('./images/dummy_image.png') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg__image"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I try to print only 'text' on page not the entire page ...

If you want to take out specific parts of the page from print version, use `@media print` CSS rules:

```
@media print {
    #images {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not exactly the problem I have. Images can be printed or not it's not matter. after print images disappear from page. I want to prevent this.

Comment: I should have made myself clear: you should not use your javascript, but instead use media rule.